# SQL Server four column composite key of various data types

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, composite-primary-key

I have just been reviewing a vendors database schema when I can upon a table that has a composite primary key on four columns, three of which are floating point data types. I am not sure why but this really shocked me.

What are the implications / benefits of having this kind of composite primary key? Is it recommended? I thought floats were dangerous as primary key fields.

[image]

Comment: Could check this links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105260/sanity-check-floats-as-primary-keys
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318455/using-datetime-float-representation-as-primary-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this models what is known in CAD as "family table"<sup>1</sup>. In essence, one "logical geometry" can generate many "physical geometries" by **just** varying dimensions<sup>2</sup>, instead of adding or removing geometrical features.

As its name suggests, it's a table - columns are dimensions and each row represents a particular combination of values of these dimensions that should be applied on particular "instance" to produce the physical geometry, which looks awfully similar to what you are showing us here.

There is no purpose in generating two geometrically identical instances, so these dimensions form a key<sup>3</sup>, which is fine as long as all components of the system "understand" that some numbers (e.g. decimal 0.1) [cannot be represented exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1089026/533120) in binary floating-point no matter what the precision.

Depending on where your data comes from (and where it is going), you may stick with the current design or consider using [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) instead:

- For example, if your data comes from (or is consumed by) a CAD API, it is probably represented as a `double` there already, so there is less friction just storing it as `float` in the database.
- If it comes from some UI where user is expected to enter it in decimal numeric system, `decimal` might be a better choice.

---

*<sup>1</sup> "Family table" is a PTC Pro/ENGINEER (aka. Creo) term. The essentially same thing is known as "iParts/iAssemblies" in Autodesk Inventor and "configurations" in SolidWorks.*

*<sup>2</sup> And other aspects of the parametric design such as feature suppression, but let's not get caught up into too much detail right now...*

*<sup>3</sup> And you do need it regardless of whether you'll introduce additional "surrogate"  key and make it primary.*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to delete this key and replace it with id key auto increment on table. it's recommended to use integer type for your key, good luck

Comment: Unfortunately its not my database. Its a table from a 3rd party vendor.

Comment: i understand your problem Phil

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything particularly "wrong" with a FLOAT key.  The proper type should reflect the column values.  [Here is a relevant SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105260/sanity-check-floats-as-primary-keys)